# Total number of odd numbers in a row of Pascal's triangle is a natural power of two

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

This seems like a combinatorial problem so there might be something simple that hasn't struck me.
Although I do have an idea but I am unable to proceed from it.
The statement of the question is:

> Prove that in any row of [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), the number of odd elements is $2^k$, for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I was working on a Pascal's triangle but in a binary format, where two adjacent 1's add up to 0. Something of the sort:

```
                 1
               1   1
             1   0   1
           1   1   1   1
         1   0   0   0   1
       1   1   0   0   1   1
```

It is a definitive sequence and the thing I liked about it was that you can add up the adjacent 1's in a row to get the number of odd elements, but I haven't been able to generalize this information.
I was thinking along the lines of a recursive relation in polynomials whose coefficients would represent the rows of this triangle, then I can just feed 1 into the equation and inductively prove that it is a perfect power of 2.

Can someone help me out on a proof along these lines, if I'm going in the right direction here?

P.S. I know there is the modulo 2 proof but can someone help me generalize that binary pascal's triangle?

Comment: This will be helpful: https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/30001.4-5.shtml

Comment: Okay, cool. But I want to try a proof along the lines of what I was trying. That is a good solution, but I wanna see where this goes.

Comment: To get an inductive proof, you may want to use the results from the answers based on Kummer's Theorem. That is, try to show that the number of $1$s in a row of Pascal's Triangle is $2$ to the power of the number of $1$ bits in the binary representation of $n$.

Comment: You may be interested by the fact that Pascal's triangle modulo 2 generates Sierpinski's sieve (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SierpinskiSieve.html)

Answer (score 3):

Similar idea to Andreas Caranti's answer:

Kummer's Theorem says that the number of factors of $p$ in $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of carries when adding $k$ and $n-k$ in base-$p$. There are no carries when adding $k$ and $n-k$ in binary if and only if $k\veebar n-k=0$; when that is true, $n=k\lor n-k$. This means that $\binom{n}{k}$ is odd when the $1$ bits of $k$ are a subset of the $1$ bits of $n$. That is, there are $2^{\sigma_2(n)}$ odd entries in row $n$ of Pascal's Triangle, where $\sigma_2(n)$ is the sum of the bits in the binary representation of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Will delete because this is not what OP intends, but a proof via [Kummer's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer's_theorem) looks rather neat to me.

Write $n, m$ in base $2$
$$
n =  2^{k} n_{k} + \dots + 2 n_{1} + n_{0},
\qquad
m =  2^{k} m_{k} + \dots + 2 m_{1} + m_{0},
$$
with $n_{i}, m_{i} \in \{ 0, 1 \}$.

Then

> $\dbinom{n}{m}$ is odd iff there are no carries in the sum in base $2$ 
>   $$
> m + (n - m) = n,
> $$
>   that is, iff $m_{i} \le n_{i}$ for each $i$.

Given $n$, there are thus
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{k} (n_{i} + 1)
$$
possibilities for $m$, and each $n_{i} + 1 \in \{ 1, 2 \}$.

This also tells you what is the exponent $k$ in the question - it is the number of $1$'s in the diadic expansion of $n$, or equivalently, the number of *distinct* powers of $2$ that sum up to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (at least simplest to explain) solution (using Lucas's theorem) has not been posted; let me fill that "much needed gap". Lazy as I am, I will mostly copypaste my answer from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2184460/ , since the argument is essentially the same.

I use the notation $\mathbb{N}$ for the set $\left\{0,1,2,\ldots\right\}$.

The question asks the following:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, the number of $i \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$ such that $\dbinom{n}{i}$ is odd is a power of $2$.

I shall prove something slightly more general:

> **Theorem 2.** Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $q$ be a real number. Then, there exists a finite subset $G$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that
>   \begin{align}
> \sum\limits\limits_{\substack{i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
> ;\\\dbinom{n}{i}\text{ is odd}}} q^i = \prod_{g \in G} \left(q^{2^g} + 1\right) .
> \end{align}

*Proof of Theorem 2.*
Write $n$ in the form $n=a_{k}2^{k}+a_{k-1}2^{k-1}+\cdots+a_{0}2^{0}$ for some
$k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_{0},a_{1},\ldots,a_{k}\in\left\{  0,1\right\}  $.
(This is just the base-$2$ representation of $n$, possibly with leading zeroes.)

[Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas's_theorem) tells you
that if $i=b_{k}2^{k}+b_{k-1}2^{k-1}+\cdots+b_{0}2^{0}$ for some $b_{0}
,b_{1},\ldots,b_{k}\in\left\{  0,1\right\}  $, then
\begin{align}
\dbinom{n}{i}
&\equiv
\dbinom{a_{k}}{b_{k}}\dbinom{a_{k-1}}{b_{k-1}}
\cdots\dbinom{a_{0}}{b_{0}}=\prod\limits_{j=0}^{k}\underbrace{\dbinom{a_{j}}{b_{j}}
}_{\substack{=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }b_{j}\leq a_{j}\\
0, & \text{if }b_{j}>a_{j}
\end{cases}
\\\text{(since }a_{j}\text{ and }b_{j}\text{ lie in }\left\{  0,1\right\}
\text{)}}} \\
&=\prod\limits_{j=0}^{k}
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }b_{j}\leq a_{j}\\
0, & \text{if }b_{j}>a_{j}
\end{cases}
=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }b_{j}\leq a_{j}\text{ for all }j\text{;}\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\mod 2 .
\end{align}
Hence, the $i\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $\dbinom{n}{i}$ is
odd are precisely the numbers of the form $b_{k}2^{k}+b_{k-1}2^{k-1}
+\cdots+b_{0}2^{0}$ for $b_{0},b_{1},\ldots,b_{k}\in\left\{  0,1\right\}  $
satisfying $\left(  b_{j}\leq a_{j}\text{ for all }j\right)  $.
Since all these $i$ satisfy $i \in \left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$
(because otherwise, $\dbinom{n}{i}$ would be $0$ and therefore could not
be odd), we can rewrite this as follows: The
$i \in \left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$ for which $\dbinom{n}{i}$ is
odd are precisely the numbers of the form $b_{k}2^{k}+b_{k-1}2^{k-1}
+\cdots+b_{0}2^{0}$ for $b_{0},b_{1},\ldots,b_{k}\in\left\{  0,1\right\}  $
satisfying $\left(  b_{j}\leq a_{j}\text{ for all }j\right)  $.
Since these
numbers are distinct (because the base-$2$ representation of any
$i\in\mathbb{N}$ is unique, as long as we fix the number of digits), we thus
can substitute $b_{k}2^{k}+b_{k-1}2^{k-1}+\cdots+b_{0}2^{0}$ for $i$ in the
sum $\sum\limits\limits_{\substack{i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\
\dbinom{n}{i}\text{ is odd}}}q^{i}$. Thus, this sum rewrites as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{\substack{i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\
\dbinom{n}{i}\text{ is odd}}}q^{i}
&=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{\substack{b_{0},b_{1}
,\ldots,b_{k}\in\left\{  0,1\right\}  ;\\b_{j}\leq a_{j}\text{ for all }j}
}}_{=\sum\limits_{b_{0}=0}^{a_{0}}\sum\limits_{b_{1}=0}^{a_{1}}\cdots\sum\limits_{b_{k}=0}^{a_k}
}\underbrace{q^{b_{k}2^{k}+b_{k-1}2^{k-1}+\cdots+b_{0}2^{0}}}_{=\left(
q^{2^{k}}\right)  ^{b_{k}}\left(  q^{2^{k-1}}\right)  ^{b_{k-1}}\cdots\left(
q^{2^{0}}\right)  ^{b_{0}}} \\
&=\sum\limits_{b_{0}=0}^{a_{0}}\sum\limits_{b_{1}=0}^{a_{1}}\cdots\sum\limits_{b_{k}=0}^{a_{k}
}\left(  q^{2^{k}}\right)  ^{b_{k}}\left(  q^{2^{k-1}}\right)  ^{b_{k-1}
}\cdots\left(  q^{2^{0}}\right)  ^{b_{0}} \\
&=\left(  \sum\limits_{b_{k}=0}^{a_{k}}\left(  q^{2^{k}}\right)  ^{b_{k}}\right)
\left(  \sum\limits_{b_{k-1}=0}^{a_{k-1}}\left(  q^{2^{k-1}}\right)  ^{b_{k-1}
}\right)  \cdots\left(  \sum\limits_{b_{0}=0}^{a_{0}}\left(  q^{2^{0}}\right)
^{b_{0}}\right)  \\
&=\left(  \sum\limits_{b=0}^{a_{k}}\left(  q^{2^{k}}\right)  ^{b}\right)  \left(
\sum\limits_{b=0}^{a_{k-1}}\left(  q^{2^{k-1}}\right)  ^{b}\right)  \cdots\left(
\sum\limits_{b=0}^{a_{0}}\left(  q^{2^{0}}\right)  ^{b}\right)  \\
&=\prod\limits_{g=0}^{k}\underbrace{\left(  \sum\limits_{b=0}^{a_{g}}\left(  q^{2^{g}}\right)  ^{b}\right)  }_{\substack{=
\begin{cases}
q^{2^{g}}+1, & \text{if }a_{g}=1;\\
1 & \text{if }a_{g}=0
\end{cases}
\\\text{(since }a_{g}\in\left\{  0,1\right\}  \text{)}}} \\
&=\prod\limits_{g=0}^{k}
\begin{cases}
q^{2^{g}}+1, & \text{if }a_{g}=1;\\
1 & \text{if }a_{g}=0
\end{cases}
\\
&=\left(  \prod\limits_{\substack{g\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,k\right\}  ;\\a_{g}
=1}}\left(  q^{2^{g}}+1\right)  \right)  \underbrace{\left(  \prod\limits
_{\substack{g\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,k\right\}  ;\\a_{g}=0}}1\right)  }_{=1} \\
&=\prod\limits_{\substack{g\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,k\right\}  ;\\a_{g}=1}}\left(
q^{2^{g}}+1\right) .
\end{align}
Thus, there exists a finite subset $G$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align}
\sum\limits\limits_{\substack{i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\\dbinom{n}{i}\text{ is odd}}} q^i = \prod_{g \in G} \left(q^{2^g} + 1\right)
\end{align}
(namely, $G$ is the set of all $g\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,k\right\}$ satisfying $a_g = 1$). This proves Theorem 2. $\blacksquare$

*Proof of Theorem 1.* Theorem 2 (applied to $q = 1$) shows that there exists a finite subset $G$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align}
\sum\limits\limits_{\substack{i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\\dbinom{n}{i}\text{ is odd}}} 1^i = \prod_{g \in G} \left(1^{2^g} + 1\right) .
\end{align}
Consider this $G$.
Comparing
\begin{align}
\sum\limits\limits_{\substack{i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\\dbinom{n}{i}\text{ is odd}}} 1^i = \prod_{g \in G} \underbrace{\left(1^{2^g} + 1\right)}_{= 1+1 = 2}
= \prod_{g \in G} 2 = 2^{\left|G\right|}
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
\sum\limits\limits_{\substack{i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\\dbinom{n}{i}\text{ is odd}}} \underbrace{1^i}_{=1}
& = \sum\limits\limits_{\substack{i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\\dbinom{n}{i}\text{ is odd}}} 1 \\
& = \left(\text{the number of all $i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$ such that $\dbinom{n}{i}$ is odd}\right) \cdot 1 \\
& = \left(\text{the number of all $i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$ such that $\dbinom{n}{i}$ is odd}\right) ,
\end{align}
we obtain
\begin{align}
\left(\text{the number of all $i\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$ such that $\dbinom{n}{i}$ is odd}\right) =  2^{\left|G\right|} .
\end{align}
Hence, the number of $i \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$ such that $\dbinom{n}{i}$ is odd is a power of $2$. This proves Theorem 1. $\blacksquare$